# How do I correctly set up a way for users to set up a meal plan?

Tags: php, database, laravel, controller, store

I am trying to set up a basic way for users to create a meal plan for a week. I've attempted to do this a few ways but as it's my first project I've seriously stuck atm.

So below I'll show the steps that I have taken and explain my thoughts as I go.

## create_meal_plans_table.php

I like to keep the tables as simple as possible however it may be my downfall. I originally had the days Monday to Friday shown as separate strings however it was messy and decided to place it in its own day's table.

I then added a title so that on the user profile they could choose a specific meal plan from a dropdown, and it would be shown.

The rest speaks for itself.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateMealPlansTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('meal_plans', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('day_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('breakfast');
            $table->string('lunch');
            $table->string('dinner');
            $table->string('snack');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('meal_plans');
    }
}
```

## create_days_table

I am unsure whether leaving the days as strings is correct or not.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateDaysTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('days', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->mediumText('monday'); //medium height text
            $table->mediumText('tuesday'); //medium height text
            $table->mediumText('wednesday'); //medium height text
            $table->mediumText('thursday'); //medium height text
            $table->mediumText('friday'); //medium height text
            $table->mediumText('saturday'); //medium height text
            $table->mediumText('sunday'); //medium height text
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('days');
    }
}
```

## Meal/create.blade.php

Rather than explain this I will screenshot how it looks and show it below.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <head>

        <style>

            table .button {
                background-color: transparent;
                border: none;
                color: black;
                padding: 16px 32px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 16px;
                margin: 4px 2px;
                /*transition-duration: 0.4s;*/
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            table {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
            td {
                width: 8rem;
                height: 4rem;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                text-align: center;
            }
            th {
                background: lightblue;
                border-color: white;
            }

            body {
                padding: 1rem;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>


    <div class="container">

        <form action="/mp" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            @csrf

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8 offset-2">

                    <div class="row pb-3">
                        <h1>Add Meal Plan</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">

                        <table class="table" >

                            <tr>
                                <td><button class="button-1 button">MON</button></td>
                                <td><button class="button-2 button">TUE</button></td>
                                <td><button class="button-3 button">WED</button></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td><button class="button-4 button">THURS</button></td>
                                <td><button class="button-5 button">FRI</button></td>
                                <td><button class="button-6 button">SAT</button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><button class="button-7 button">SUN</button></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </div>

                    <header>Enter Meals</header>

                    <div class="form-outer">

                        <form action="/mp" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                            @csrf

                                <div class="field">

                                    <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Day</label>

                                    <select>

                                        <option> --Select Tags--</option>

                                        <option id="monday"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                name="monday">
                                            Monday</option>

                                        <option id="tuesday"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                name="tuesday">
                                            Tuesday</option>

                                        <option  id="wednesday"
                                                 class="form-control"
                                                 name="wednesday">
                                            Wednesday</option>

                                        <option  id="thursday"
                                                 class="form-control"
                                                 name="thursday">
                                            Thursday</option>

                                        <option  id="friday"
                                                 class="form-control"
                                                 name="friday">
                                            Friday</option>

                                        <option  id="saturday"
                                                 class="form-control"
                                                 name="saturday"
                                        >Saturday</option>

                                        <option  id="sunday"
                                                 class="form-control"
                                                 name="sunday"
                                        >Sunday</option>

                                    </select>

                                    @if ($errors->has('day_id'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('day_id') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                                    @endif

                                </div>

                                <div class="field">

                                    <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Breakfast</label>

                                    <input id="breakfast"
                                           type="text"
                                           class="form-control{{ $errors->has('breakfast') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                           name="breakfast"
                                           value="{{ old('breakfast') }}"
                                           autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('breakfast'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('breakfast') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif

                                </div>

                                <div class="field">

                            <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Lunch</label>

                            <input id="lunch"
                                   type="text"
                                   class="form-control{{ $errors->has('lunch') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                   name="lunch"
                                   value="{{ old('lunch') }}"
                                   autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('lunch'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('lunch') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                            @endif

                                </div>

{{--                                <div class="field">--}}

{{--                            <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Snack</label>--}}

{{--                            <input id="snack"--}}
{{--                                   type="text"--}}
{{--                                   class="form-control{{ $errors->has('snack') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"--}}
{{--                                   name="snack[]"--}}
{{--                                   value="snack3{{ old('snack') }}"--}}
{{--                                   autocomplete="name" autofocus>--}}

{{--                            @if ($errors->has('snack'))--}}
{{--                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">--}}
{{--                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('snack') }}</strong>--}}
{{--                        </span>--}}
{{--                            @endif--}}

{{--                        </div>--}}

                                <div class="field">

                            <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Dinner</label>

                            <input id="dinner"
                                   type="text"
                                   class="form-control{{ $errors->has('meal') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                   name="dinner"
                                   value="{{ old('dinner') }}"
                                   autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('dinner'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('dinner') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                            @endif

                                </div>

                            <div class="field">

                                <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Snack</label>

                                <input id="snack"
                                       type="text"
                                       class="form-control{{ $errors->has('snack') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                       name="snack"
                                       value="{{ old('snack') }}"
                                       autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('snack'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('snack') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                                @endif

                            </div>

{{--                                <div class="field">--}}

{{--                                    <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Snack</label>--}}

{{--                                    <input id="snack"--}}
{{--                                           type="text"--}}
{{--                                           class="form-control{{ $errors->has('snack') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"--}}
{{--                                           name="snack[]"--}}
{{--                                           value="snack4{{ old('snack') }}"--}}
{{--                                           autocomplete="name" autofocus>--}}

{{--                            @if ($errors->has('snack'))--}}
{{--                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">--}}
{{--                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('snack') }}</strong>--}}
{{--                        </span>--}}
{{--                            @endif--}}

{{--                                </div>--}}

                                <div class="row pt-4">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Add New Post</button>
                                </div>

                        </form>

                    </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    </body>

@endsection
```

The select day dropdown will be corrected.

[image: Post Meal Plan]

## MealPlanController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\MealPlan;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MealPlanController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['show']]);
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = auth()->user()->following()->pluck('profiles.user_id');

        $plans = MealPlan::whereIn('user_id', $users)->with('user')->latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('meal.create.index', compact($plans));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('meal.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'day_id' => 'required',
            'breakfast' => 'required',
            'lunch' => 'required',
            'dinner' => 'required',
            'snack' => 'required',
        ]);

        auth()->user()->plans()->create([
            'day_id' => $data['day_id'],
            'breakfast' => $data['breakfast'],
            'lunch' => $data['lunch'],
            'dinner' => $data['dinner'],
            'snack' => $data['snack'],

        ]);

        return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\MealPlan  $mealPlan
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(MealPlan $mealPlan)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\MealPlan  $mealPlan
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(MealPlan $mealPlan)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\MealPlan  $mealPlan
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, MealPlan $mealPlan)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\MealPlan  $mealPlan
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(MealPlan $mealPlan)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Whenever trying to post it, it just refreshes the page. Please whatever advice I can get would be appreciated. I could even pass along my email if I could get further advice otherwise difficult to explain on here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lot more to improve here.

Change your day table like this

```
Schema::create('days', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id();
   $table->string('day');
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

Then you should write a seeder like this

```
public function run()
{
    $days = [
        ['id' => 1, 'day'  => 'Monday'],
        ['id' => 2, 'day'  => 'Tuesday'],
        ['id' => 3, 'day'  => 'Wednesday'],
        ['id' => 4, 'day'  => 'Thursday'],
        ['id' => 5, 'day'  => 'Friday'],
        ['id' => 6, 'day'  => 'Saturday'],
        ['id' => 7, 'day'  => 'Sunday'],
    ];

    foreach ($days as $key => $day) {
        DB::table('days')->insert($day);
    }
}
```

Then it would be easy to get the days in the dropdown list.

You should put a name attribute for select box. Now you have name attribute for option. Thats wrong.

Snack is an array or just string? you have both there. Since you are storing it like text. It should not be an array.

Finally store should be changed

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request()->validate([
        'day_id' => 'required',//Should come from the days table
        'breakfast' => 'required',
        'lunch' => 'required',
        'dinner' => 'required',
        'snack' => 'required',
    ]);

    auth()->user()->plans()->create([
        'day_id' => $request->get('day_id'),
        'breakfast' => $request->get('breakfast'),
        'lunch' => $request->get('lunch'),
        'dinner' => $request->get('dinner'),
        'snack' => $request->get('snack')
    ]);

    return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
}
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: I initially wanted to add three different snacks to the entry, so one after breakfast, after lunch and after dinner. However, i thought as a first iteration i should just keep it simple. So, i added the seeder as you mentioned however, to fill the drop down was being a little annoying. i used the following code in the view --- 
                            @foreach($days as $day)
                                <option value="{{ $day}}"> </option>
                            @endforeach

Comment: Also I used dd(\request()->all()); and got back                                                         array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "1ZpvmJvtIDYyF9CpHs3Q1AX4YqpZFXVzxbPB5w6h"
  "days_id" => "Monday"
  "breakfast" => "jhbjbub"
  "lunch" => "bjh"
  "dinner" => "bjb"
  "snack" => "jb"
] So, i am confused to where it keeps failing

Comment: <select name="day_id">
@foreach($days as $day) 
<option value="{{ $day->id}}">{{$day->day}} </option> 
@endforeach
</select>

And you will get an id of the day for day_id

Comment: Check the laravel log for error message. It will guide you to the error.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems like something is broken, it keeps saying undefined variable $days, and just to be sure I defined it in the public function create (), but the issue keeps repeating itself.

Comment: If you can, please upload the project in the Git and share it with me. Then I can help you

Comment: Hi, Sorry! My laptop had an issue and i took it into repair. I had to install everything again and realised that i downloaded the incorrect version of Laravel which was causing the issue